# How do I compose redux connect and withCookies in my App?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm using `react-cookies` and `react-redux` in my react application, and I'm trying to compose them, but when I do, I receive this error:

> You must pass a component to the function returned by connect. Instead
>   received {}

Below is my code:

```
//index.js
ReactDOM.render(
  <CookiesProvider>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
        <App />
      </ConnectedRouter>
    </Provider>
  </CookiesProvider>,
  document.querySelector("#root") //Id root at index.html
);

//App.js
class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchUser();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <div className="container">
            <Route exact path="/" render={() => (<Login cookies={this.props.cookies}/>)} />
            <Route exact path="/surveys" render={() => (<Landing cookies={this.props.cookies}/>)} />
            <Route exact path="/login" component={Landing} />
            <Route exact path="/surveys/new" component={SurveyNew} />
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(
  null,
  actions
)(withCookies(App));
```

Answer (score 2):

The `connect` function in redux which expected to get react component as a parameter, but `withCookies` may return a different value.

so change the export function as below and try.

```
export default withCookies(connect(null, actions)(App));
```